# Condition to check if an image is not in correct orientation and then correct it's form before processing?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, keras

I am using keras-retinanet model to detect an object from an image. Problem I am facing with this is if image is not orientated correct then model is unable to detect the object. For example if image is like this:

[image: sample input image]

If I manually flip this image by 180 then model is able to detect the object.

I am doing following image processing before sending to model-

```
def _preprocess_image(self, image):
    draw = image.copy()
    draw = cv2.cvtColor(draw, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = preprocess_image(image)
    image, scale = resize_image(image)
    return draw, image, scale
```

In above method how can I add a check if orientation is not correct and then can correct it?

Comment: I'm afraid this detection is the subject to another network.... But I think a good network will recognize the objects even when flipped.

Comment: try to detect once for each possible orientation of the image or train your network with samples of each orientation

Comment: Training on each orientation is an alternate. Yet I thought there will be another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrain the network with data augmentation containing all the orientations.

I don't think it is possible to determine that the image is in the original position or flip by 180°.

Unless if the origin (0,0) top left position is recorded in the meta data of the image and you have/find access to the metadata of the image itself (very unlikely possibility imo).